# Is there anyway to tell if I'm facing/receiving a punishment?

Tags: league-of-legends

[Note: this question is partially related to the Tribunal](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/tribunal/en/faq/)

Recently I went to try and review cases in the Tribunal (I recently turned lv. 20), but it wouldn't let me no matter what I did.

My honor hasn't been reset (because if you get a punishment from them it should be reset), and I can't really tell if I am facing/receiving a punishment or not. Is there anyway to tell if I'm facing/receiving a punishment? I'm very confused.

Comment: When it "wouldn't let you," did it say anything? Did you get any messages? How exactly did it prevent you? Was an interface element unresponsive/disabled? I don't know much about LoL and especially not how to assess your status in its semi-automated player-moderation system, but some more detail might help resolve your issue, even if it may not be able to answer your question.

Comment: Based on some research, if you were receiving a punishment, it would be obvious as "a warning, suspension, name change, or in severe cases, permanent banning" are plain to see (the warning would be in your e-mail). If a punishment is being decided for you, it's unclear if it would prevent tribunal access because it's unclear if that deliberation is part "receiving a punishment". This further leads me to suspect something else may be the problem here.

Comment: @skovacs1 Thanks for the help, but after trying about after 30 minutes it worked. Not sure why it wouldn't work a little bit ago.

Comment: Might not have updated that your lvl 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *receive* a punishment you will be informed the reason for the punishment and what the punishment is. However, if you are currently awaiting judgement by the tribunal you are not informed. This is because there is no reason to tell people they are on tribunal, it just causes them to worry unnecessarily if they didn't deserve it. Not informing players also prevents players from trying to manipulate tribunal because they don't know they are currently awaiting judgement. 
As you found out, the issue with not being able to pass judgement is unrelated. I believe you can still pass judgement on other players while awaiting judgement yourself, though this may have been changed.

Answer (score -2):

If you haven't gotten ANY message SAYING SPECIFICALLY that you are being punished, you are NOT being punished. Same goes for league promotion, getting the honorable opponent/friendly badges, ect.

As far as the tribunal goes, if you have done silly things, it is possible for them to have temporarily taken these rights off of you without notifying you (It isn't really a punishment, you don't get banned/your stats reset)

A friend of mine got banned for reporting too many people in LoL and he got a message explaining it.

Here is a tip from me: You don't want to have anything to do with the tribunal until you have several hundred games (Like 600-700) and have played quite a bit of ranked. You have yet to see the full array of rages, whiners, trolls and feeders. Trust me. After having a game with feeders in your team you might want to go there and 'clean' the community, but things don't really work that way.

Simply put: Play the game, enjoy yourself, stay away from the tribunal.

Comment: I feel you strayed entirely too far from the topic here, and inserted your own opinion on top of it.

Comment: I agree about the opinion, however what exactly doesn't have to do with the situation?

Comment: everything beyond the first two sentences.

Comment: Alright, I agree. I will try to make less of these mistakes in the future.